# CKAN homepage redirection issue

Tags: browser-cache, ckan

**Issue:**

I am having a website developed in CKAN framework. I am struggling with a sporadic issue which is happening on my machine only. When i do some manual changes into CKAN database and tries to click on any menu or a link it is redirecting me to homepage.

After updating the database, i run the command for re-indexing the datasets using production.ini file, so that everything should be updated on the application, but nothing happened.

**Temporary Solution**

Following steps gives me temporary solution for this issue:

1. On the website, i need to press F12 button.
2. Then on the browser, i need to do right click on reload button.
3. Select the third option ie. "Empty cache and hard reset" will refresh the page and issue get resolved.

This is the temporary solution. If i came back on next day and try to click on other menu then again it redirected me to homepage.

**Note:** This issue is happening only on Chrome browser.

Please help me get a permanent solution to get rid of this caching issue.
Comments are appreciable.

Comment: From your temporary solution this looks like caching issue. Can you reproduce the issue while browsing the site from private browser session?

Comment: On private browsing the issue is not reproducible. On normal browsing on chrome browser, again the issue is reproduced. Even yesterday i have cleared the cache and application was working fine, but today i am getting the same issue.